# How to set sql field value equal to another value in the same table but just for the query (don't want to actually update the original table)

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I would like to write which would replace the field1 value in the table with the field2 value if its null or some other state that I can't conceive of yet. I don't however actually want to update the table, I just want this to be done for the query alone.

Comment: Search for `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`

Comment: You probably want a CASE statement if it's more than just null values, e.g. `SELECT CASE WHEN field1 is NULL THEN field2 WHEN field1 = 'X' THEN 'Y' ELSE field1 END...`

Answer (score 0):

You can return values based on a condition using the [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) statement:

```
SELECT  CASE FieldOne
        WHEN NULL THEN FieldTwo
        ELSE FieldOne
        AND AS FieldOneName
FROM    TableThing
```

Or the [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function:

```
SELECT ISNULL(FieldOne, FieldTwo) FROM TableThing
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a small set of undesirable values, besides NULL, which should be converted to specific value then this SQL expression using [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms177562.aspx) works nicely:

```
isnull(nullif(nullif(field1, undesiredValue1),undesiredValue2),substituteValue) as field1NewName
```